# Xcode Error: 'src/core/lib/gprpp/sync.h' file not found - Issue with gRPC-C++ in iOS Project

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, pubs

I am using firebase in my project and when I try to install cloud_firestore and try to run on ios, it get me to this error.

error looks like this:

```
Lexical or Preprocessor Issue (Xcode): 'src/core/lib/gprpp/sync.h' file not found
/Users/uditmishra/Desktop/hydration-hero/ios/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/core/ext/transport/binder/clie
nt/connection_id_generator.h:23:9

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 15.
```

my pubspec.yml file looks like:

```
name: flutter_application_1
description: "A new Flutter project."

publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.3.0 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6
  firebase_core: ^2.26.0
  firebase_auth: ^4.17.7
  firebase_messaging: ^14.7.18
  cloud_firestore: ^4.15.7

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^3.0.0


flutter:

  uses-material-design: true
```